# how to resolve ajax call once issue

Tags: ajax

**Drupal code**

```
function form_example_form($form, &$form_state)
{

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'form_example') . '/js/test.js');

    $form['price_form'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Add Item'),
    );

    $form['price_form']['item'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Item Name?',
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 25,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => array(
            // #ajax has two required keys: callback and wrapper.
            // 'callback' is a function that will be called when this element changes.
            'callback' => 'form_example_simplest_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'listDiv',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );

    $form['price_form']['textfields'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="listDiv">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#markup' => '',
    );

    $form['price_form']['price'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Item Price?',
        '#size' => 10,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['price_form']['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
    );
    if (!empty($form_state['values']['item'])) {
        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {item} where item_name='" . $form_state['values']['item'] . "'");
        if ($result->rowCount() != 0) {
            $form['price_form']['textfields'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'Already exist',
            );
        } else {
            $form['price_form']['textfields'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'New Item',
            );
        }
    }

    return $form;
}

function form_example_simplest_callback($form, $form_state)
{
    return $form['price_form']['textfields'];
}
```

On blur of item textfield,I am showing status of item whether item_name exist in database or not.But It is showing perfectly for first time.

As it replaces a form name with 'form_name-2' after first ajax callback,it is not working afterwards.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really set prefix and suffix for `$form['price_form']['textfields']` and in AJAX callback return `$form['textfields']` instead? Or is it only a mistake made when you trimmed your code for upload here?

Comment: @molot,Code is not trimmed.It showing a status message perfectly for first time which I am setting using '#markup'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you set your wrapper div in `$form['price_form']['textfields']`, but in the AJAX callback you are replacing it with the `$form['textfields']` that does not have it defined. To be safe, keep these guidelines:

1. Never use the same identifier at 2 different depths of an form array, as it leads to mistakes. Be sure to set `'#tree' => TRUE` if you need to use identifier twice, to avoid conflicts.
2. In AJAX callback always return the same element you set `'#prefix' => '<div id="...">` on.
3. Be sure to only define each element once. If you are using

   ```
   $form['price_form']['textfields'] = array(
     '#prefix' => '<div id="listDiv">',
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
     '#markup' => '',
   );
   ```

   to define element, don't reset it with `$form['price_form']['textfields'] = array(` later in code. Using `array()` creates new *empty* array effectively deleting everything set earlier. Write directly to it's members like this:

   ```
   $form['price_form']['textfields']['#markup'] = t('Already exist');
   ```

Of course they are not set in stone, but don't break them unless you know why and what you're doing. In your case, you have `'textfields'` twice, you are setting wrapper on one and returning another. That's why it only works once. Second time there is no element FAPI's AJAX is supposed to replace.

Comment: _Never use the same identifier at 2 different depths of an form array_ Pretty sure that's not true (the core field system does it all the time, for example). The important thing to note is that `#tree` should be used where there are, or will be, duplicates

Comment: @Clive I meant it as a guideline for ones who aren't fluent with form api, not as a rule. See the paragraph below list. But I expanded my answer and added `#tree` to it - I admit I oversimplified it.

Comment: Would up-vote again if I could :)

Comment: @Molot,Thanks for response,But I edited a code as your suggestion,Still is working fine for first time.Why?

Comment: Now in `$form['price_form']['textfields'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'Already exist',
            );` you are creating textfields anew - without prefix and suffix. Make it `$form['price_form']['textfields']['#markup'] = t('Already exist');` - and so on.

Comment: @Molot,Thanks a lot,Now understood concept also.Actually this mess is happening due to referring some another example But thank you again...

Comment: @SwapnilPatil well, examples aren't pure universal perfection. If it's here on Drupal Answers, feel free to link it, and we may try to fix it.

Comment: @Mołot,I referring sample examples from drupal site.But It is not example fault.Actually in example they are creating a new form control so no issue Before I didn't got this thing.

Comment: Tanks a lot, my issue resolved by this post, thanks :)